# Converting Buffer to String on a Redis Get in a Node.js Heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

This is my very basic GET function

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.contentType('application/json');
  var lid = request.param("lid");
  client.llen(lid, function(reply, len){
      client.lrange(lid, 0, len-1, function(reply, messages){
      console.log(messages);
      response.send(messages);
    })
  });
});
```

For some reason, the console output and the response i get looks like

```
[ <Buffer 5b 7b 22 6c 61 77 79 65 72 5f ... 61 64 61 74 61 22 3a 22 36 22 7d 5d> ]
```

I'm storing these as JSON strings:

```
client.lpush(lid, JSON.stringify(to_store))
```

Any ideas why my response is not a JSON string??

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(messages.toString());
```